# Why is the Container's add function faster with an Array with objects then with an Array with Sencha Touch objects

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to figure out what is better to use when working with Sencha Touch 2 (speed wise). I already figured out that it makes virtually no difference if I initialize the components shown on the screen through `Ext.create` or `{xtype:""}`. But I how about if I where to add controls to a container like this:

```
containerPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            id: 'appContgdfsainer',
            fullscreen: true,
            items: Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                text: 'Button',
                listeners: {tap:function(){containerPanel.add(items)}}
            })

        });
```

Note that items is an Array containing either 1000 panels created with `{html:"test", xtype:"panel"};` or with `Ext.create("Ext.Panel",{html:"test"});`
This gives me other results then I'd expect. What I expect is that the `Ext.create` will be faster because sencha only has to add the component which is already created using the `Ext.create` function. I'd expect the other possibility to be slower because sencha first has to create this object before it can be added.
Only the problem is, it isn't.
The `{html:"test", xtype:"panel"};` is noticeably faster to load the panels then when I use Ext.create to add them.

**Question:**
How come that when adding panels to a container `{html:"test", xtype:"panel"};` is faster then `Ext.create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you determining `faster`?

I created a quick test on jsperf.com - and it showed that using `Ext.create` is faster.

Link: http://jsperf.com/st2-xtype-vs-create

Comment: Normally I'd work with timers to determine what is faster. But this was clearly visible to the eye which one was faster. I checked your link and this clearly depicts Ext.create being faster. On the other hand I created a container with a single button. This button, when tapped, adds 1000 panels to the container. In this case the pre created panels take longer to add then the object form. Your test does confuse me a little. What I think the difference is, is that I add the panels after the container is rendered.

Comment: Your test adds the panels and then renders the container, already containing the panels. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: In my tests the `containers` DOM is rendered in memory (all components work this way in Sencha Touch 2). If I change the before test statement to add the container to the Viewport (which means it will actually be visible, though not in the tests) the test results are the same. ref: http://jsperf.com/st2-xtype-vs-create/2

Comment: Are you able to produce a testcase and send it my way? I'll take a look into it (I'm on the ST team).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed help, for some reason I can't reproduce the results. I tried in a few scenario's but in all scenario's `Ext.create` is indeed faster (what you'd expect). Also the second time I add the same panels the time to add is so much lower then with `{xtype:"panel"}` its about 4ms vs 3000ms. I think there were external factors playing a part in why I was getting this conflicting results. Probably the IIS server. So thanks again, the conflict was not created by sencha touch it was by some other external factor.